# How to send an object through request phpunit

Tags: php, mysql, phpunit, laravel-8

Hello I am new to Laravel and PHP.
This is the controller for my Student Model

```
{
    public function create(Request $request){

        $student = new Student();
        $student->fname = $request->fname;
        $student->lname = $request->lname;
        $student->dob = $request->dob;
        $student->address = $request->address;
        $student->course = $request->course;
        $student->year = $request->year;

        $student->save();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

This is the unit test I wrote, basically just putting an object in the request and then adding it to the database using an instance of the controller I wrote(i don't know if this is the best way to do it).

```
class AddStudTest extends TestCase
{   

    use refreshdatabase;

    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function test_addStud()
    {   
        
        $test = new Models\Student; 
        $test->fname = 'Test';
        $test->lname ='User';
        $test->dob ='2000-04-05';
        $test->address ='test address';
        $test->course ='BS Tester';
        $test->year ='1';
        
        $request = new Request(compact($test));
        $testController = new Http\Controllers\StudentController;
        $testController->create($request);
       
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('students',[
            'fname'=>'Test',
            'lname'=>'User',
            'dob'=>'2000-04-05',
            'address'=>'test address',
            'course'=>'BS Tester',
            'year'=>'1'
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I run phpunit, it says:

```
1) App\AddStudTest::test_addStud
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'fname' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `students` (`fname`, `lname`, `dob`, `address`, `course`, `year`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?))
```

How do I get it to read the object I put in the request? And if there's a better way to do it I hope someone can educate me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad! I just have to send the array data with keys instead of just the values.

```
 $test = array('fname'=>'Test','lname'=>'User','dob'=>'2000-04-05','address'=>'test address','course'=>'BS Tester','year'=>'1');
```

Still, if there's a better way to do this, I would gladly accept it.